# Picache gif is a still image (Expo + ReactNative)

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to speed up loading a bunch of gifs, but a big limitation is that I'm using Expo, and don't want to detach. I found [Picache](https://github.com/benawad/Picache), which states it can be used just like react native Image. When the page loads though, everything loads super fast now, but the gifs are still and not 'gify'.

```
<Picache
   source={{uri: someURL.gif)}}
   style={{height: 300, width: 300, borderRadius: 10}}
/>
```

I've spent so long trynig to figure out how to speed up loading a bunch of images without detaching. Is there a way to make Picache work with gifs, or a similar easy way to implement?

**Before someone suggests, I've already tried... [react-native-fast-image-expo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fast-image-expo) but unfortunately it requires detaching as well. That is the desired package though.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to bring out the project, you can replace it with [this.](https://github.com/wcandillon/react-native-expo-image-cache)

Until Expo added the module,

example:

```js
import {Image} from "react-native-expo-image-cache";

// preview can be a local image or a data uri
const preview = { uri: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mNk+M9QDwADhgGAWjR9awAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" };
const uri = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/react-native-e.appspot.com/o/b47b03a1e22e3f1fd884b5252de1e64a06a14126.png?alt=media&token=d636c423-3d94-440f-90c1-57c4de921641";
<Image style={{ height: 100, width: 100 }} {...{preview, uri}} />
```

**Get the local image from a remote URI**

```js
import {CacheManager} from "react-native-expo-image-cache";

const {uri} = this.props;
const path = await CacheManager.get(uri).getPath();
// if path is undefined, the image download has failed
```